# How can I make the Earth rotate around it's axis in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

So I want to represent the Earth rotating for a number of seconds from a tspan knowing that  a full rotation happens in 86160 seconds. It means that for 239.33 seconds , the Earth rotates with a degree. The problem is that I don t know how to use the rotate command in a right way.
This is the code:

```
    tspan=[0 :72000];
[X,Y,Z]=sphere(50);
R=6400000;
earth = imread('earth.jpg');
globe= surf(-X*R,Y*R,-Z*R);
image_file='earth.jpg';
cdata = imread(image_file);
set(globe, 'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', cdata,  'EdgeColor', 'none');
set(gcf,'Color','k')
set(gca, 'visible', 'off')
axis equal
view (90,0)
rotating=1; % 1 degree ever 239.33 seconds from tspan
rotate(earth, [0 1 0],1) % test to see if it's working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of rotating the earth, rotate the camera using `view`, try

```
...
axis equal
for n=0:90
   view(90+n,0)
   pause(1)
end
```

Comment: I was thinking more of make it rotate, because I have to plot a satellite's orbit around the Earth and it would look better if the camera stays still, but this is also a good solution.

Comment: then you need to multiply the position matrix by a rotation matrix in one direction...